# Using Panda's .at function to modify multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm a little bit confused with the usage of `at`. From the website:

> Access a single value for a row/column label pair.

Nonetheless, I can still use it to change values in multiple rows. For instance:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 2, 3], [0, 2, 1], [10, 20, 30]], index=[0, 1, 2], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

    A   B   C
0   0   2   3
1   0   2   1
2  10  20  30

idxs = df[df.B==2].index.values
df.at[idxs, 'A'] = -33

    A   B   C
0 -33   2   3
1 -33   2   1
2  10  20  30
```

This will in fact change the values in both the first two rows (column `A`).
Am I doing something wrong? Is it safe using `at` to change multiple rows this way?

Comment: agree with you, documentation is not accurate in the sense that `at` allows non single value access/modification. Good catch!

Comment: While it technically works it's not advisable to use this behavior.  This behavior is not tested, so it may change between releases.  It is also generally slower than `loc` when providing multiple values, albeit not by much.  Additionally this only works for setting and will fail for lookups.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, .at is accessing single value for a row/column label pair and changing it one at a time. But your variable idxs is a list so it is executed for every index in the list. 
So the answer to your question is no, you are doing nothing wrong and yes, it is perfectly safe to use .at to change multiple rows this way.